# Read the package.json name in the serverless.yml

Tags: serverless-framework

Instead of manually defining the service name in `serverless.yml` I'd like to read the `name` from the package.json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve a dynamic service name based on the `package.json` app name I took advantage of the variable import Serverless Framework feature.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-javascript-files

This loads the file `package.json` and specifies that the name property should be applied to the service entry.

```yaml
# serverless.yml
service: ${file(./package.json):name}
```